# No Row inserted when using hibernate example

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jdbc

I, trying to use Hibernate 3.5.3 with Postgresql 8.4 and PostGreSQL-8.4.701.jdbc4.jar 
and after transaction completed no actually data inserted into table.

this is the table:

```
   CREATE TABLE doolloop2.dluser
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  firstname character varying(255),
  lastname character varying(255),
  email character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE doolloop2.dluser OWNER TO doolloop2;
```

I'm trying to map the following class into this table

```
public class DlUser {
    private long Id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    public DlUser()
    {

    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.Id = id;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return this.Id;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String name) {
        this.firstname = name;
    }
    public void setLastName(String name) {
        this.lastname = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstname;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastname;
    }
}
```

Then I have my hibernate.cfg.xml which looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
org.postgresql.Driver</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/doolloop2</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username">doolloop2</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password">doolloop</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
      <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
      <!-- Mapping files -->
      <mapping resource="DlUser.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My DlUser.hbm.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.doolloop.DlDataServices.Session.DlUser" table="DlUser">
  <id name="Id" column="id" >
        <generator class="assigned"></generator>
 </id>
  <property name="firstName">
     <column name="firstname" />
  </property>
  <property name="lastName">
    <column name="lastname"/>
  </property>
  <property name="email">
    <column name="email"/>
  </property>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The main code looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = null;
    try{
          // This step will read hibernate.cfg.xml and prepare hibernate for use
          SessionFactory sessionFactory = new 
    Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
           session =sessionFactory.openSession();
            //Create new instance of Contact and set values in it by reading them from form object
             System.out.println("Inserting Record");
            DlUser user = new DlUser();
            user.setFirstName("Test");
            user.setLastName("Test");
            user.setEmail("Test@yahoo.com");
            session.save(user);
            System.out.println("Done");
          // Actual contact insertion will happen at this step
          session.flush();
          session.close();
       }
       catch(HibernateException ex)
       {
           System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
       }              
}
```

and Console output is the following:

```
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:09 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate 3.5.3-Final
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:09 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:09 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:09 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:09 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:09 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:09 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: Reading mappings from resource : DlUser.hbm.xml
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
INFO: Mapping class: com.doolloop.DlDataServices.Session.DlUser -> DlUser
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: Configured SessionFactory: null
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: Hibernate connection pool size: 10
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: autocommit mode: false
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: using driver: org.postgresql.Driver at URL: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/doolloop2
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: connection properties: {user=doolloop2, password=****}
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: RDBMS: PostgreSQL, version: 8.4.4
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JDBC driver: PostgreSQL Native Driver, version: PostgreSQL 8.4 JDBC4 (build 701)
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.JdbcSupportLoader useContextualLobCreation
INFO: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory buildTransactionFactory
INFO: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory getTransactionManagerLookup
INFO: No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JDBC batch size: 15
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Scrollable result sets: enabled
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Connection release mode: auto
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Default batch fetch size: 1
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Generate SQL with comments: disabled
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory createQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO: Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Query language substitutions: {}
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Second-level cache: enabled
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Query cache: disabled
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory createRegionFactory
INFO: Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Echoing all SQL to stdout
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Statistics: disabled
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Default entity-mode: pojo
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Named query checking : enabled
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Check Nullability in Core (should be disabled when Bean Validation is on): enabled
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl <init>
INFO: building session factory
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory addInstance
INFO: Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: Running hbm2ddl schema update
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: fetching database metadata
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: updating schema
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: table found: doolloop2.dluser
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: columns: [id, email, lastname, firstname]
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: foreign keys: []
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: indexes: [users_pkey]
Sep 25, 2010 2:45:10 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: schema update complete
Inserting Record
Done
Hibernate: insert into DlUser (firstname, lastname, email, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Then, when I'm selecting from this table, it's empty. I googled for a long time but haven't found any wise explanation what is happening here. Could anybody just help?

Thank you in advance,
Danny.

Comment: Are you using Logger ? Try to put it into debug mode for hibernate and JDBC libraries. Maybe it'll help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define clear transaction boundaries by beginning and committing transactions and to run your persistent code inside these boundaries. As mentioned in the Javadoc of the `Session`, a typical transaction should use the following idiom:

```
Session sess = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx;
try {
    tx = sess.beginTransaction();
    //do some work
    ...
    tx.commit();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
    throw e;
}
finally {
    sess.close();
}
```

#### See also

- [Sessions and transactions](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Sessionsandtransactions)

Comment: I use this skeleton in my servlets' base class.

Comment: @Tony This was more intended to be a comment to your answer but didn't fit well in the comment box :) Up to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Commit your transaction.  The log file says autocommit is off.

Comment: Thank you, you're absolutely right Transaction ts = session.beginTransaction();
         ts.commit(); solved the problem.